# PowerShell two parameters either of them can be null but not both null

Tags: validation, powershell, parameters, null

I'm wondering if this can be done at the parameter level rather in code:
I have 2 parameter: $School and $Class

```
Get-Students -School SchooName # Will give me all Students name in all classes in that School
Get-Students -Class ClassName  # Will give me all Students name in that Class across all schools
Get-Students                   # Should return parameter level error.
```

I tried to use following:

```
function Get-Students{
param(
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="School no null")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$School,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="School no null")]
    [AllowNull()]
    [string]$Class,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="Class no null")]
    [AllowNull()]
    [string]$School,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="Class no null")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Class
)
}
```

But it doesn't work in this way...

Hope I explained this correctly. Or if there is no way can do this from parameter only inside of the code?

Thanks
River

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**. The following *commented* code snippet is based on [Add a parameter to multiple *Parameter Sets*](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2013/01/add-a-parameter-to-multiple-parameter-sets-in-powershell.html) article. Allows supplying `-Class` or `-School` parameter or  **both** of them all together.

```
function Get-Students{
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$SomeThing, # any type instead of [switch]
    # ↑↑↑ parameter(s) in all Parameter Sets

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,  ParameterSetName="School No Null")]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,  ParameterSetName="Class And School")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$School,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,  ParameterSetName="Class No Null")]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,  ParameterSetName="Class And School")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Class
)
    Write-Host $PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ForegroundColor Cyan
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) 
    { 
        "School No Null"   { "$School/*,$($SomeThing.IsPresent)"; break} 
        "Class No Null"    { "*/$Class,$($SomeThing.IsPresent)";  break}
        "Class And School" { "$School/$Class,$($SomeThing.IsPresent)";  break}
    }
}
Get-Students -Class "A"
Get-Students -School "West" -SomeThing
Get-Students -Class "A" -School "West"

### errors raised:
#   Get-Students
### Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
### + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Get-Students
#   Get-Students -Class ""
#   Get-Students -School ""
### Cannot validate argument on parameter '…'. The argument is null or empty.
### + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Get-Students
```

**Original answer** (a code snippet based on [PowerShell V2: ParameterSets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets/) article from *PowerShell Team Blog* and on [*MSDN* help article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters)) **does not allow** supplying **both** `-Class` and `-School` parameters all together:

```
function Get-Students{
param(
 [parameter(Mandatory=$true,  ParameterSetName="School No Null")][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Class No Null")] #[AllowNull()]
 [string]$School,

 [parameter(Mandatory=$true,  ParameterSetName="Class No Null")] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="School No Null")]#[AllowNull()]
 [string]$Class
)
    Write-Host $PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ForegroundColor Cyan
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) 
    { 
        "School No Null" { $School; break} 
        "Class No Null"  { $Class;  break}
    }
}

### valid calls:

Get-Students -Class "A"
Get-Students -School "West"

### errors raised:
### Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
# Get-Students
# Get-Students -Class "A" -School "West"
### The argument is null or empty.
# Get-Students -Class ""
# Get-Students -School ""
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think this is the correct answer! Which means the Variable should only appear once but with different parameter conditions!

Answer (score 0):

You can test them in code instead of trying to stuff this check into parameter set.

```
if ($School -eq $null -and $Class -eq $null) {throw "School and Class must not be null together!"}
```