# How to define a Parameter Set in which no parameter is required(PS cmdlet)?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to Define three parameter sets

1. cmdletName - param1   (ParameterSet1)
2. cmdletName - param1 -param2  (ParameterSet2)
3. cmdletName (this does not have any parameter)(ParameterSet3)

How can I do this?

This is how my current code look like.

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = ParameterSet1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, HelpMessage = "The ResourceGroupName")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = ParameterSet2, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, HelpMessage = "The ResourceGroupName")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = ParameterSet3, Mandatory = false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, HelpMessage = "The ResourceGroupName")]
    public String ResourceGroupName { get; set; }

[Parameter(ParameterSetName = ParameterSet2, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, HelpMessage = "The name of metric alert rule")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = ParameterSet3, Mandatory = false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, HelpMessage = "The ResourceGroupName")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can't use a param like a switch AND as if it takes a string array..

Comment: [Related my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385089/3439404) documented here: [Adding Parameter Sets to a Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/developer/cmdlet/adding-parameter-sets-to-a-cmdlet). _Each parameter set must have at least one unique parameter. **If possible**, make this parameter a mandatory parameter._ Add a _fake_ optional parameter to the `ParameterSet3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define three parameter sets
>
> - `cmdletName -param1`         (ParameterSet1)
> - `cmdletName -param1 -param2` (ParameterSet2)
> - `cmdletName` (this does not have any parameter)(ParameterSet3)
>
> How can I do this?

Here's possible *commented* Powershell solution with some debugging outputs:

```
function cmdletName{
param(
    [parameter( Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="ParameterSet1",
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [parameter( Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="ParameterSet2",
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    ### [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$param1,

    [parameter( Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="ParameterSet2", 
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    ### [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$param2,

    [parameter( Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="ParameterSet3",
                DontShow, HelpMessage="dummy parameter")]
    [string]$AnythingFake='?'

)
process {

    Write-Host $PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ForegroundColor Yellow
    # The following `switch` statement calls a different method 
    #       based on which parameter set the user has specified.
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) 
    { 
        "ParameterSet1" { "$param1/*/*";        break} 
        "ParameterSet2" { "$param1/$param2/*";  break}
        "ParameterSet3" { "*/*/$AnythingFake";  break}
        Default         { throw "impossible";   break}
    }
}}
```

Possible usage examples

```
# Prepare parameters for pipeline
$par1 =  [PSCustomObject]@{param1='p1p'}
$par12 = [PSCustomObject]@{param1='P1P';param2='p2p'}

# Possible valid call                 # ParameterSetName
cmdletName -param1 "p1"               # ParameterSet1
cmdletName -param1 "P1" -param2 "p2"  # ParameterSet2
cmdletName                            # ParameterSet3
$par1 | cmdletName                    # ParameterSet1
$par12 | cmdletName                   # ParameterSet2
```

Results:

```
ParameterSet1
p1/*/*
ParameterSet2
P1/p2/*
ParameterSet3
*/*/?
ParameterSet1
p1p/*/*
ParameterSet2
P1P/p2p/*
```